# How to Send JSON object to ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, json, jms, activemq-classic

I am creating JSON object as below

```
org.json.JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I want to send this object to queue on ActiveMQ.
I was trying to use following API

```
objectMessage.setObject(json);
```

But as json object is not serializable, compiler is throwing error.

If I convert json object to String then it is working.

Is there any way I can directly transfer json object (without converting to String) to queue?

Comment: Why dont you Send a HTTP Request with JSON as payload?

Comment: Is there any reason you want the a JSONObject to be sent over the wire? For creating this object you are using the string representation anyway so why not use it. If you have POJO classes representing your json (if you are using jackson or gson for example) then you could serialize and send these objects but it won't be as efficient as the string representation.

Comment: Hi  DerStoffel could you provide me an example?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use ..jms.ObjectMessage, it leads to all sorts of pain, suffering and anger. Serialize your JSON to a string and send a ..jms.TextMessage instead.

That being said.. it all depends on your use case. There are Architectural principles that favor text-based formats during transport for cross-platform and service independence reasons. If this is a use case where the same app is sharing data b/w itself over JMS, the argument could be made to justify using ObjectMessages. To do that update your JSON pojo's to ".. implement Serializable" and then jms.ObjectMessage will work.

Comment: Thats what I am doing right now. I am converting JSON to String and using String

Comment: Is there any better way?

Comment: see edit. "better" is a pretty subjective goal.. would need more details to provide an answer that best fits your use case